# Water and methyl in fuel tank

Tags: fuel-tank

The water in my fuel tank is getting picked up by the pump when I go uphill or downhill. I added a half pint of methyl hydrate, but that only raised the water level. The car will stall and spit for 5 minutes when the water gets picked up. My siphon cannot reach the bottom of the tank.

I will be scrapping the 93 Lesabre soon, so I cannot drop the tank because of cost.

I will pump it out following the good comments below.

Comment: If you disconnect the fuel line at the fuel filter, you should be able to drain the tank by turning the key to the on position (may have to do it many times). If you put the car at an angle of which you experience the water ingest, then disconnect the fuel where it goes into the filter, extend the line out so you have it going into the appropriate type of container, by turning the key on/off many times, you should be able to drain the tank of all the water without worrying about other chemicals in your tank. Just a thought.

Comment: Instead of turning the key on and off, you can remove the fuel pump relay and jump terminals 30 and 87

Comment: @Jupiter - noice suggestion :o)

Comment: And one other thing, you don't want to run you fuel tank dry of fuel. Your fuel pump is cooled by the fuel. If it runs dry, you'll most likely kill your pump. Get the water out and stop pumping.

Comment: You don't need to drop the tank, there's probably an access to the tank under the back seat, you could drain the water out through that with your hose.

Comment: I now have the car at a good angle and I will pump it out into gas cans using the connection at the fuel filter. I will use a pushbutton switch on a long cable that is connected to bypass the fuel pump relay.

Question: is there any problem running the fuel pump continuously, or is it designed to be always running? Is it a diaphragm type pump? I will immediately stop the pump as soon as I see the fuel stop flowing.